# Set language preferences using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set the languages preferences for a webpage but  can't seem to get it. What happening is that as soon as the page loads it goes to localhost/en/en , it's repeating itself and I don't know why. This is my code:

```
languageOptions = ['en', 'zh-cn', 'zh-hk', 'jp-jp', 'ko-kr', 'th-th'];
languageDictionary = {
  'en': 'en',
  'en-gb': 'en',
  'en-us': 'en',
  'zh': 'cn',
} 



function checkLanguage() {
    setTimeout(() => {

let lang = localStorage.getItem('lang');
if (this.changeLanguage(lang)) {
    window.location.href = lang;
} else {
    window.location.href = 'en';
}

let browserLang = navigator.language.toLocaleLowerCase();

if(this.languageDictionary[browserLang]) {
    window.location.href = browserLang;
} else {
    window.location.href = 'en';
}

let urlLang = window.location.pathname.replace('/', '');

if (this.languageOptions.indexOf(urlLang) !== -1) {
    window.location.href = urlLang;
} else {
    window.location.href = 'en';
}
})
```

};

```
checkLanguage();

function changeLanguage(lang) {
    console.log(lang);
    // add to storage
    window.location.href = '' + lang;
    localStorage.setItem('lang', lang)
}
```

Is there something in my code that is causing this?

Comment: Please create a plunker/fiddler for this.

Comment: As soon as you set location.href, the browser will reload the page. All the code after the first if statement will never be exe6

Comment: @PatrickHund oh I see thank you I didn't know that (very new here). Do you know of a solution to that? Or how I can set that language?

Comment: Try removing the else blocks and put the location.href statement where you set the default language "en" at the end, without an if block. Sorry, can't post proper answer, on my way to work